# Showing LAtex formulas in GitHub markdown.md

Tags: html, github, latex, markdown

Showing LAtex formulas in GitHub markdown.md

#### (1) Code1 : used  `render.githubusercontent`

```markdown
Here <img src ="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=\color{black}F=P(\frac{i}{n})^{nt}"> and the calculation of value <img src ="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=\frac{\sum_{x_i \in R_{ij}} {r_{im}}}{\sum_{x_i \in R_{ij}} p_{i,m-1}.(1-p_{i,m-1})}"> is done.*The texts and mathematical expressions are not properly aligned. Also it doesnt look pretty for reading.*
```

[image]

#### (2) Code2: `Latex`

```latex
Here $F=P(\frac{i}{n})^{nt}$ and the calculation of value $\frac{\sum_{x_i \in R_{ij}} {r_{im}}}{\sum_{x_i \in R_{ij}} p_{i,m-1}.(1-p_{i,m-1})}$ is done.*The texts and mathematical expressions are properly aligned. Looks prettier than the first part.*
```

[image]

I want to write the mathematical expressions along with the english sentences for `README.md`file on github.The code2 of latex is not working on github site(without extensions) !.  Is it possible to get the results of code2 by changing the code1 little bit and using the knowledge of html in markdown file?

**Note**: Don't want to use extensions for rendering the Latex on Github. And I have no knowledge of HTML, CSS etc.
For reference please follow this [link](https://gist.github.com/a-rodin/fef3f543412d6e1ec5b6cf55bf197d7b)

Comment: LaTeX is not part of [the original Markdown language](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), nor is it part of [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/). See the attached duplicate for possible alternate solutions.

Comment: @Chris I have gone through the  attached shared question, but couldn't able to find any alternate solutions. Let me ask you a simple thing :  Is it possible to adjust the image vertically which is rendered by `render.githubusercontent.com` in the read me file by using the `html` language. ? If yes , then please help me to do that and if its not then   there is nothing for discussion :).

Comment: [Probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44831505/354577)